# DirectX & Oculus setup inside Visual Studio, main, precompiled headers, linker and files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directx-11, oculus

Goal: I'm trying to develop my first simple Oculus rift application using visual studio.

Background: Computer Engineer/programmer of arbitrary languages-rusty at C++/very rusty at visual studio/inexperienced with 3D balls to the wall programming.

DirectX Progress: I found this excelent tutorial (http://3dgep.com/introduction-to-directx-11/) and I rebuilt it walking thru the code; this taught me a lot. My code never actually would run though, likely an issue with linkers or precompiled headers, so I reverted back to the original Demo File.

Oculus Progress: I've learned a lot about using the LibOVR, successfully compiled my first program which was to gather sensor data. Never ran it though.

Visual Studio: I currently have one solution setup, with two projects (DirectXTemplate and LibOVR). I'm thinking I should merge the two projects and turn the DirectXTemplate into a library so I can access all the functions defined in these files (though I will likely need to modify them as development progresses). **How do I go about doing this? Is this the right thing to do?**

I also have some general questions:

1. List item

   Projects/Solutions: what is the difference and how should I lay things out to achieve my goal?
2. List item

   My winAPI main function is in my own cpp file, it calls functions from directXtempalte... most of these are working except the LoadContent function fails about half way thru, I think due to the shaders. I'm really confused about the shaders in the tutorial, particularly walking about at compile time vs. at run time shaders and suspect its an issue with the Linker, precompiled headers, include directories or something like that. There are so many views of the properties tab in VS its causing more confusion and errors. So my real question here is how do I control this better? I mean, the properties window changes depending on what project/solution/file I select and it also changes based on the mode selected in the properties window... getting the properties window right for all these objects has proven to be a highly error prone process requiring iterative trial and error... this really really sucks and wastes tons of time... **How can it be avoided?**
3. List item

**How do I turn the directX template in to a library like the LIBOVR and should I?** Keep in mind the directX template/library will be updated massively as the project progresses but LIBOVER will not be. When all things are done, I'll be using the LIBOVR functions for to deal with the oculus (this is static but is updated by the Vendor) and DirectXTemplate/Library functions to deal with direct X (this will be custom build, using the template as the starting point.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).